# jQuery click images to show next ones

Tags: jquery, function, click, show-hide

I am attempting to display 8 images, all hidden on page load by css except the first one. When you click the first one, it should hide that one and display the next one. So on and so forth.

I've got this working using `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` and it's set to a timer, but I want to simply replace that fade in/out effect with a click function.

How would I go about doing that?

```
   var journey_img = $('#the_journey_dialog img');

   function navigateImages() {
      var current = journey_img.filter(".active"), next;
         if (current.length == 0 || (next = current.next()).length == 0 ) {
            next = journey_img.slice(0,1);
         }              

     current.removeClass('active').fadeOut(400).promise().done(function(){
        next.addClass('active').fadeIn(); 
     });
     setTimeout(navigateImages,7*1000);
  }
  navigateImages();


<div id="the_journey_dialog">
    <img src="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/images/1.jpeg" border="0" />
    <img src="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/images/2.jpeg" border="0" />
    <img src="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/images/3.jpeg" border="0" />
    <img src="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/images/4.jpeg" border="0" />
    <img src="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/images/5.jpeg" border="0" />
    <img src="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/images/6.jpeg" border="0" />
    <img src="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/images/7.jpeg" border="0" />
    <img src="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/images/8.jpeg" border="0" />
</div>
```

Comment: so on click you do not want the fade in/out effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will loop, pause on hover and allow you to **click to advance:**

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ajopud/14/edit)**</kbd>

```
var $dia = $('#the_journey_dialog'),
    $img = $dia.find('img'),
    c = 0, // CURRENT COUNTER
    intv;

function anim() {
  $img.fadeTo(500,0).eq( ++c%$img.length ).stop().fadeTo(500,1);
}
function auto() {
  intv = setInterval(anim,2000);
}

$img.eq( c ).show();
auto();

// PAUSE ON HOVER
$dia.hover(function(e) {
   return e.type=="mouseenter" ? clearInterval(intv) : auto();
}).click( anim ); // AND CLICK TO ADVANCE
```

Comment: Wow, that's great! I don't need it to fade though and can't even have it auto play. So you went above and beyond :) How would I simplify this and remove the animations and the interval?

Comment: I did not read your comment cause I got no notification, sorry... Hope you resolved this one! All you need is to remove unneeded stuff like the auto() and hover() and have only `$dia.click( anim );`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
navigateImages.click(function(){
    var current = navigateImages.filter('.active'), next = current.next();
    if(!next.length){
        next = navigateImages.get(0);
    }

    current.hide().removeClass('active');
    next.show().addClass('active');
})
```